# Customize "Continue Reading" text

Tags: themes

I am using "twenty seventeen" theme for my blog. I need to change text of "Continue reading" link. Could you please help me?

Thanks,
Dmitriy Reznik

Comment: please consider to ask in https://wordpress.org/support/theme/twentyseventeen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution (or problem) is not limited to the 2017 theme. This is something you can add to any theme. Since it involves changing the `functions.php` file, you should first make a Child Theme of the 2017 theme. (Ask the googles how to do that....and why you would use a Child Theme rather than changing the theme code.)

In fact, if you had asked the googles the same question, the first result would have been the Codex, where all is revealed. https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More .